# Could not transfer artifact from central : Received fatal alert: protocol_version

Tags: java, maven, java-6

I'am working on a legacy java 6 project and i'm facing issues related to resolving dependencies. I found out based on similar issues that it is related to TLS protocol since central only supports TLSv1.2 while java 6 uses TLSv1.1. Is there any workaround that can help me to solve it ?

Comment: I tried adding `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2` but still not working

Comment: You have to use a more recent Java version at least Java 7 which support TLSv1.2 but Java 6 does not... https://central.sonatype.org/faq/tls-info/#answer_1 (may be you should use a repository manager within your corporate environment...